Given two non-empty sets $A$ and $B$, prove that $A \times B = B \times A$ if and only if $A = B$
Prove: Two non-empty sets $ A $ and $ B $ satisfy $ A \times B = B \times A $  if and only if $ A = B $.
Let $ j \in A \wedge n \in B $, then $ (j,n) \in A \times B $ and $ (n,j) \in B \times A $.
We assume that $ A \neq B $, so $ \exists u, v \mid u \neq v $ such that $ u \in A \wedge v \in B $. From $ u,v $, the ordered pair $ (u,v) $ exists, which is a subset of  $(n,j) $, and also the ordered pair $ (v,u) $, which is a subset of $ (j,n) $.
Given that $ u \neq v $, it is demonstrated by the theorem of ordered pairs that $ (u,v) \neq (v,u) $.
If we suppose that $ A \times B = B \times A $, this is not true when $ A \neq B $ because it implies stating $ \{(u,v)\} = \{(v,u)\} $, which we have seen is not true.
However, if $ A = B $, then there exists a set $ \{h \mid h = (n,j) \wedge n = j \}$, which is a subset of both $ (j,n) $ and $ (n,j) $, with which the equality $ \{(n,j)\} = \{(j,n)\} $ holds, and with it, the initial hypothesis $ A \times B = B \times A $.

Direct way seems more practical: from $A=B$ conclusion is clear. Now remain to prove, that $A \times B = B \times A \Rightarrow A=B$.

More generally $A\times B=C\times D$ if and only if either $A=C$ and $B=D$. or else $A\times B=\varnothing=C\times D$.

I think its easier to prove directly, here is how I would do it. Here we do this side of the equivalence ($A\times B =B\times A \implies A = B$) since the other is trivial.
proof. Let $(a, b)\in A\times B$, then we have that $(a,b)\in B\times A$ since $A\times B = B\times A$. By definition of Cartesian product we have, $(a,b)\in B\times A \implies a\in B \text{ and } b\in A$, which concludes the proof since for any element of one set, we can find it in another set. So $A=B$

Another way to proceed.
Let us prove the implication $(\Rightarrow)$ first.
Suppose that $x\in A$ and $y\in B$. This implies that $(x,y)\in A\times B = B\times A$.
In other words, this implies that $x\in B$ and $y\in A$.
On the one hand, this means that $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$.
On the other hand, the last sentence implies that $A = B$ (axiom of extensionality), and it's done.
Let us prove the implication $(\Leftarrow)$ now.
If $A = B$, then $A\times B = A\times A = B\times A$, and we are done.
Hopefully this helps!

Let's take any $a \in A$. For any $b \in B$ we have $(a,b) \in A \times B = B \times A$, so $a \in B$ i.e. we obtain $A \subset B$. Reverse  use same way.

@Angae MT, I see your suggestion, but do not understand why you want to delete a note on non-emptiness, can you explain, please?

Hi zkutch, just want to say the question is restricted to nonempty of $A,B$ only, deleting is just to prevent from misleading, you can add it as a remark actually.

Of course you are right, @Angae MT, I just only now see this restriction. Thanks for remark, I'll revert your edition.
